# Occasional WCF 5 seconds response spikes

Tags: c#, wcf

We are developing a client-server system where the client connects to a service and fetches an image from a buffer. The request runs at 25 hertz (25 requests per second) over a NetTcpBinding. The image data which is sent contains the image buffer (byte[]) and some meta data about the image.

What we are experiencing is that occasionally, the server does not respond for 5 seconds (5020 to 5050 ms), and we can't figure out why.

Running svc logging on the client we see the following

```
Activity Boundary                   Suspend       10:00:00:000
Activity Boundary                   Resume        10:00:00:003
Received a message over a channel   Information   10:00:05:017
```

This occurs **both when running the server as a managed WCF service, and an unmanaged WWS service**

It can happen once every 100.000 requests, once per night, or several times per minute at seemingly random intervals.

Does anyone know what might cause this issue?

Comment: For random performance gaps, my first suspect would be the garbage collector. You can use GC.Count(n) to get the current count for each generation, with n = 0, 1, or 2. Collect counts periodically, and compare across performance spikes.

Comment: If it happens when running as an unmanaged WWS - doesn't that mean it is probably unrelated to both C# and WCF? I would start by looking at windows perf-mon to see what else happens at that point in time.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you have `100.000` to such precision?

Comment: @Inuyasha I'm Norwegian and we use , and . opposite of how it's used in English. So we would write 100.000,00 instead of 100,000.00

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you use the term "umanaged WWS" service ?

Comment: @havardhu, that wasn't the question.  I will rephrase.  Why did you give the number with *three* significant decimals (thousandths)?

Comment: Unamaged = C++, WWS = WWSAPI, a windows native web service api for c++ (so not WCF)

Comment: @Inuyasha Because I wrote one hundred thousand, not one hundred dot 3x zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the solution buried in the Microsoft customer support database.

> The 5 second delay is due to the firing of the SWS(Silly Window
>   Syndrome) avoidance timer. The SWS timer is scheduled to send the
>   remaining data which is less than 1 MSS (Maximum Segment Size, 1460
>   bytes) and the receiver is supposed to send an ACK advertising the
>   increased receive window and indicating that the remaining data bytes
>   can be sent. However, if the receiver sends an ACK when it can be
>   ready for sufficient buffer within 5 seconds, the SWS timer cannot
>   recover the 5 seconds delay status due to a race condition.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020447

This issue only occurs when using localhost or 127.0.0.1. The delays do not occur when running the service and client on different machines.